# SQL nested aggregate functions

Tags: sql, oracle, select, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to get the lowest average rating for Movies in a database.

Currently I have:

```
select movie.movietitle as "Lowest Average Rating"
from movie, rating 
where movie.movieid = rating.movieid
group by movie.movietitle
having avg(rating.rating) = min(avg(rating.rating));
```

But I'm getting the error "group function is nested too deeply."
Can anyone provide me with a correct way of doing this and explain why this doesn't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MOVIETITLE AS "Movie Title", AVG(RATING) AS "Lowest Average Rating"
FROM MOVIE, RATING
WHERE MOVIE.MOVIEID = RATING.MOVIEID
GROUP BY MOVIETITLE
HAVING AVG(RATING) =
(
    SELECT MIN(AVG(RATING)) AS "AVGRating"
    FROM MOVIE, RATING
    WHERE MOVIE.MOVIEID = RATING.MOVIEID
    GROUP BY MOVIETITLE
)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*simple example*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a3f2/31)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*simple example*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a3f2/33)

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I should rephrase.  I meant "Find the movie title of the movie with the lowest average rating."

Comment: @Sam have you seen the results on sqlfiddle?

Comment: Hmm, yes I see that.  For some reason, when I run it against my data I get many results.